# Can any one give explanation on LSA and what is different from NMF?

Tags: clustering, svd, latent-semantic-indexing, doc2vec

LSA is better way for extracted new concepts from large text documents collections .. in the following example :

i have spend lot of time in Google to get explanation about the following

[image]

My questions are:

The result matrix Vtk .. similarity matrix can be build based on cosine similarity for all documents .. now how do we use this matrix for document clustering ?

can some one give a brief explanation how can we get Ak matrix .. is this matrix contain the original Term-Document matrix with reduced version?

thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You never compute Ak. Too expensive. It will usually be less sparse than A, so even worse. Ak is a **reconstruction of the original term-document matrix**.

For clustering, you could use V_k, the documents x topics matrix.

But usually you wouldn't even do clustering, you would hope the topics (factors) already are what you are looking for.

As a matter of fact, you can formalize k-means the very same way, as a matrix decomposition. Uk is the matrix storing your centroids, sigma is identity, and Vk is a binary matrix with exactly one 1 for every document. k-means *is* a matrix factorization.

Comment: regard this note : For clustering, you could use V_k, the documents x topics matrix. .. so is k-means working on this matrix .. is this right?

Comment: Do you mean im using NMF (non-negative matrix factorization) where NMF give two matrices are U and V and applying k-means. is this right or do you mean some thing else?

Comment: No. I am saying that k-means is also a variant of NMF. And why would you apply NMF twice in a row? You certainly can, but it lacks any good reason to do so.

Comment: ok, so the result matrix Vk for documents x Topics ... how do we clustering similar documents .. ? can i use cosine to find ( documents x documents ) matrix similarity based in cosine .. then applying such algorithm ? what do you think about that ? thanks

Comment: You have the "clusters" right there in the matrix. You are done.

Comment: Ok, i believe and honest to follow you notes.. its really experience in data analysis .. so my similarity matrix (docs x docs ) based on extracted topics by LSA .. is this matrix required any clustering algorithms to find similar groups .. i can determine similar group based on cosine values but i need to some Machine algorithm to do that instead of human self.. for my project work .. thank alot

Comment: There is no dxd matrix. That is too expensive. And don't use clustering if you only want similarity search. You mix up things.

Comment: can you,  please sir help me in this question .. this what i need exactly .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168166/using-k-means-for-document-clustering-should-clustering-be-on-cosine-similarity

Comment: That is a very different question. And I did not say it works. In my opinion, text clustering with k-means is a waste of time, because the results are entirely useless.

Comment: can you please sir suggest to me how do we cluster documents in Vk matrix ? thanks this is my final dot

Comment: They are already clustered there. It's the topic assignment.